# Почему не ставятся зависимости в python django под ubuntu server?

Tags: python, django, pip, requirements.txt

Ставлю зависимости для `python django` под `ubuntu server 20.04`

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

одна из зависимостей не ставится

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmlrpclib==1.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xmlrpclib==1.0.1
```

что можно попробовать?

- `pip` обновлял (`pip install --upgrade pip`)
- пробовал ставить без версии `xmlrpclib` и `xmlrpc`, не работает
- `requirements.txt` формировал за счет `pipreqs`

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос может быть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676943/how-to-install-xmlrpclib-in-python-3-4), но это не точно

Comment: вроде оно, просто не понятно, получается эту библиотеку надо вообще удалить изьrequirements, если python3 использую?

Comment: Если чесно я не знаю какой у вас код, но xmlrpclib  и xmlrpc - стандартние библиотеки.
Можете попробовать удалить из requiments.
Или запускайте главний файл и там будет писать какой у вас библиотеки нет, и так устанавливайте.